# Tkinter indexing words issue

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, indexing, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter application in python 2.7. I am using wordstart and wordend indexes to get the word that was clicked on. This works perfectly fine with regular words, but it does not work with hyphenated words.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def userOptions(event, clickposition):
    index1 = clickposition + " wordstart"
    index2 = clickposition + " wordend"
    user = text.get(index1, index2)
    print user
    return

def userEnter(event):
    text.config(cursor="hand2")
    return

def userLeave(event):
    text.config(cursor="arrow")
    return  

text = Text(master)
text.insert(INSERT, "This is a sentence\n")
text.insert(INSERT, "This is a sentence with dashes-between some-words\n")
text.pack()
text.tag_add("click", "1.0", "end")
text.tag_bind("click", "<Enter>", userEnter)
text.tag_bind("click", "<Leave>", userLeave)
text.tag_bind("click", "<Button-1>", lambda event: userOptions(event, text.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))))
text.config(state = DISABLED)

master.mainloop()
```

How do I configure this so print user can print the whole hyphenated word without splitting at the hyphen? For example, printing the string "dashes-between" instead of "dashes", "between", or "-" depending on where you click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify how `"wordstart"` defines "words". From the official documentation:

> **?submodifier? wordstart**  - Adjust the index to refer to the first
>   character of the word containing the current index. A word consists of
>   any number of adjacent characters that are letters, digits, or
>   underscores, or a single character that is not one of these. If the
>   display submodifier is given, this only examines non-elided
>   characters, otherwise all characters (elided or not) are examined.

You can use the built-in search feature of the text widget to find the start and end of the word for however you want to define "word". You can search for regular expressions, so you can search for a pattern like `[-\w]` to get either a dash or a word character.

Off the top of my head, it might look something like this:

```py
def userOptions(event):
    count = IntVar()
    pattern = r'[-\w]+'

    # find the beginning of the "word", starting _after_
    # the character clicked on
    start = "@%d,%d +1c" % (event.x, event.y)
    index1 = text.search(pattern, start, backwards=True, regexp=True)

    # starting with the beginning, find the end and save
    # the number of characters that matched.
    text.search(pattern, index1, regexp=True, count=count)

    # compute the ending index of the match
    index2=text.index("%s + %s c" % (index1, count.get()))

    # get the text
    user = text.get(index1, index2)
    print user
    return
```

By the way, your code will be much easier to understand and maintain if you avoid the use of lambda except when absolutely necessary, and it's definitely not necessary in this case. Using the above code, you can simplify the binding to this:

```py
text.tag_bind("click", "<Button-1>", userOptions)
```