# Change the definition of a word in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

When double clicking a word in a `Text`-widget the clicked word is selected. Tkinter's understanding of what a word is, however, is impractical for my use case.

[Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) explains what Tkinter considers to be a word but not how to change that. Is it possible to change Tkinter's definition of a word so that it recognizes hyphens as part of a word? I.e. I would like to select a text like `--help` or `--version` or `-U` with a double click.

Comment: This question may provide some insight/ideas for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320066/tkinter-indexing-words-issue

Comment: @curtisk that sounds very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320843/2828064) that curtisk has provided a link to Bryan Oakley states that this is not possible:

> You can't modify how "wordstart" defines "words".

But based on his answer I have developed the following method `select_current_word`, the code around is just to illustrate it's usage.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyText(tk.Text):

     def __init__(self, **kw):
         tk.Text.__init__(self, **kw)
         self.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.select_current_word)

     def select_current_word(self, event):
         i0 = self.search(r'[-\w]+', tk.CURRENT+'+1c', backwards=True, regexp=True)
         i1 = self.search(r'[^-\w]+', i0, forwards=True, regexp=True)
         self.tag_remove(tk.SEL, '1.0', tk.END)
         self.tag_add(tk.SEL, i0, i1)
         self.update()
         return 'break'

if __name__=='__main__':
     t = MyText()
     t.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
     t.insert('1.0', """
Options:
  General Options:
     -h, --help                       Print this help text and exit
     --version                        Print program version and exit
     -U, --update                     Update this program to latest version.
""".strip())
     t.mainloop()
```